# Boosted regression trees - clarification of algorithm step

Tags: regression, boosting

In my statistic learning textbook, there is an algorithm, "Boosting for Regression Trees". As step 1 in the algorithm, it is said to set $\hat{f}(x) = 0$ and $r_i = y_i$ for all $i$ in the training set, where $r_i$ represents the residuals.

Can someone explain the importance of this step?

Thanks.